# Locked between MailChimp and European Windows for CSV export?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, export

I have a CSV export for our application that is being used by end users (not tech-savvy).

For some European regional settings Excel expects a semicolon `;` for delimiting (comma is used for decimals).

Now I got to workaround this by some weird undocumented `sep=,` on the top of the Excel. This seems to work for Dutch Excel users.

Problem is that now we need to import this csv into MailChimp.

And MailChimp doesn't seem to recognize the `sep=,` on the first line, and therefore the import process seems to break. It can't recognize all the columns - I guess because MailChimp thinks these columns don't have a header.

**Question**

Is there a solution that makes it possible for Dutch Excel users to just double click on the CSV and that it works, and on the same time it can be easily imported into MailChimp without making manual edits?